# ArrayList IndexOf with a specific method?

Tags: sorting, collections, arraylist

My issue with arraylists is simple; I have a class called Score, it consists of an integer called myScore and a Name class (not relevant) called myPlayerName. I have an arraylist of these Score(s) called scoreList, and i want to be able to print out the ten highest scores in that list (a top ten list if you will), but when i call a collections.sort() method on the arraylist, it seems to return an error. I think this may be because of the fact that my score class has two parameters. how can I order an arrayList based on a specific part of an element. Is it possible to sort them by the score integer?

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: ^ Specifically the code that causes the error (if you can cut it down to a reasonable size). Who knows, it might be a really small thing.

Comment: I have a Score class (int score, int myName). I have an ArrayList of Score objects; it is called scores, i declared it as an ArrayList<Score> scores. When i try to do 
Collections.sort(scores), it returns an error. I want to sort it by the size of the score integer.

Comment: You can try getting the scores into a new ArrayList<int> and then use the function Collections.sort() on it.

Comment: I already tried that, But i want to return both the name and the score. how would I do that?

Comment: @user3133353 If this is java, have your Score implement Comparable and implement compareTo to only compare on the myScore int. Then you can have an ArrayList<Score> and do Collections.sort.

Comment: How would I do that, Dennis?